# Using an online MySQL database for an offline install of WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, local

I've begun work on a WordPress project, working offline before taking it online. I was curious, is there some way of me using the MySQL database that's online for my offline install? Would there be any way of remotely accessing it from my local MAMP setup?

Since the database is going to end up online anyway, it just feels like it makes more sense to tap the online version from the get-go rather than eventually moving it.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to make sure the remote server is accessible through network. Basically you add IP of remote server in your wordpress config and change port if it is not using default port.

Comment: @sagarchalise is correct, change this in your wp-config.php: `define('DB_HOST', 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XX');`